# Fundamental theorem of calculus sin^3

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How do I derivate the following integral:

$$F(x)=\int_{-x}^{x} \sin(t^3)\,dt$$

I have used the fundamental theorem of calculus, and I get:

$$\sin(x^3)(1)-\sin(-x^3)(-1)=\sin(x^3)-\sin(x^3)=0$$

since $\sin(x)$ is an odd function.

What should I do now?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Compute $F(0)$. Then you're done.

Comment: The answer $0$ could have been obtained without all this, since the integral is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $t\mapsto \sin(t^3)$ is odd, you can also directly get that the integral is always zero — i.e., $F(x)=0$ for all $x$.